# Deserialize XML to object in C# XmlRoot is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-deserialization

I am using asp.net (C#) website, I want to `Deserialize` the `XML` string using `XmlSerializer` class.

**My Model (.cs file)**

```
[XmlRoot("MedicalClearanceFormRoot")]
  public class MedicalClearanceViewModel
  {


    [XmlAttribute("PassengerName")]
    public string PassengerName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PhoneNo")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("BookingRefNo")]
    public string BookingRefNo { get; set; } 
}
```

**XML String**

```
<MedicalClearanceFormRoot>
  <MedicalClearanceForm PassengerName="AAAAAAAAAAAAA" Age="11" PhoneNo="TTTTTTTTTTT" Email="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" BookingRefNo="11111111111111111111" />  
</MedicalClearanceFormRoot>
```

**Code to De-Serialize the XML to Object**

```
string myXMLStringFromDB = GetXMLStringFromDb(); // this method will return XML from db.

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MedicalClearanceViewModel));
              using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(myXMLStringFromDB))
              {
               MedicalClearanceViewModel objModel = (MedicalClearanceViewModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
              }
```

But, the issue is when I De-serialize the XML to object using above code ... the properties like `PassengerName`, `Age`, `PhoneNo` Etc. are still blank in `objModel`

Can someone can help me to set the proper XML Notations on my Class on can someone can help  me to resolve this issue .

Any help will be highly appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: The properties are null because `<MedicalClearanceFormRoot>` doesn't have any attributes declared in the XML. Your hierarchies are off between the XML and the class code.

Comment: Shouldn't MedicalClearanceViewModel class have a MedicalClearanceForm property and MedicalClearanceForm have all the properties currently declared in the MedicalClearanceViewModel class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way your XML is defined, you would need to have two objects defined: 
- one for the `MedicalClearanceFormRoot` xml node
- one for the `MedicalClearanceForm` xml node

So, you have two routes you could take: add the wrapper class or change your xml.

To add a wrapper class, you would need to have a class to represent `MedicalClearanceFormRoot` which has a property for the `MedicalClearanceForm` object.  Then change your serializer class to be for the wrapper class.  Here's an example:

```
[XmlRoot("MedicalClearanceFormRoot")]
public class Wrapper
{
    public MedicalClearanceViewModel MedicalClearanceForm { get; set;}
}

public class MedicalClearanceViewModel
{

    [XmlAttribute("PassengerName")]
    public string PassengerName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PhoneNo")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("BookingRefNo")]
    public string BookingRefNo { get; set; }
}


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Wrapper));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(myXMLStringFromDB))
        {
            Wrapper objModel = (Wrapper)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

Option 2: Change your XML to look like this:

```
<MedicalClearanceFormRoot PassengerName="AAAAAAAAAAAAA" Age="11" PhoneNo="TTTTTTTTTTT" Email="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" BookingRefNo="11111111111111111111" >  
</MedicalClearanceFormRoot>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample and the code will be exactly like below. Your model is not correct.

```
 public class MedicalClearanceForm
{
    [XmlAttribute("PassengerName")]
    public string PassengerName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PhoneNo")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("BookingRefNo")]
    public string BookingRefNo { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("MedicalClearanceFormRoot")]
public class MedicalClearanceFormRoot
{


    [XmlElement("MedicalClearanceForm")]
    public MedicalClearanceForm MedicalClearanceForm { get; set; }


}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myXMLStringFromDB = @"<MedicalClearanceFormRoot><MedicalClearanceForm PassengerName = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA' Age = '11' PhoneNo = 'TTTTTTTTTTT' Email = 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' BookingRefNo = '11111111111111111111' /></MedicalClearanceFormRoot >";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MedicalClearanceFormRoot));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(myXMLStringFromDB))
        {
            MedicalClearanceFormRoot objModel = (MedicalClearanceFormRoot)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To meet the specified XML you would need this class structure I believe.

```
[XmlRoot("MedicalClearanceFormRoot")]
public class MedicalClearanceViewModel
{
    public MedicalClearanceFormElement MedicalClearanceForm { get; set; }
}

[XmlElement]
public class MedicalClearanceFormElement
{
    [XmlAttribute("PassengerName")]
    public string PassengerName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PhoneNo")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("BookingRefNo")]
    public string BookingRefNo { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: we can not apply `[XmlElement]` on class .

Comment: @Prog...why not?

Comment: we can not apply [XmlElement] on class .